# Имя выходного файла *.aab

Tags: android

Через несколько месяцев Google заставит разработчиков перейти на формат Android App Bundle (aab).
В связи с этим вопрос, если я могу в build создать имя выходного файла apk как мне надо, то если я генерирую aab, имя файла по умолчанию app-debug.aab. Как мне создать своё имя файла, по аналогии с apk?

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508720/how-to-change-the-generated-filename-for-app-bundles-with-gradle)

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо